# Static Header and Scrolling html table with d3 from csv

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am able to generate html table with d3 from csv (with conditional insertion of data in particular column) as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    svg { width:100%; height: 100% }
    table { border-collapse: collapse; color: #333; background-color: #F7F6F3; }
    table thead { font-weight: bold; background-color: #CCC; cursor: default; }
    table tbody tr:hover { background-color: #FFC; }
    td { border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 0 1ex; }
    .even { color: #284775; background-color: White; }
    .left { text-align: left; }
    .right { text-align: right; }
    .add { color: green; }
    .minus { color: red; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table"></div>
  <script>
    var table = d3.select("#table").append("table"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");
    thead.append("th").text("Title");
    thead.append("th").text("Data Change");

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
            .data(data)
        .enter().append("tr")
            .classed("even", function(d, i) { return i % 2 == 1; });
      tr.each(function(d) {
        var self = d3.select(this);
        self.append("td")
            if (a.Title === "CONDITION") {return "red"}  // <== Add these
                      else { return "black" }
            .append("a")
                .attr("href", d.URL)
                .text(d.Title);
        self.append("td")
            .html(d["Data Change"]);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

However, I am not able to make STATIC headers with scrollable body with d3. Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure d3js is the best for this, but I managed to implement what you wanted here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrLVpv?editors=0010

The scrolling part is a bit hacky because I couldn't figure out how to reverse the scrolling, so instead of looking around more for a good solution (because I'm lazy) I used the deltaY of the scroll event:

```
var scrollEvent = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .on('zoom', function (e) { 
                      var scrollDirection = (d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY > 0) ? 1 : -1;
                      startPos += (scrollDirection > 0 && startPos + increment < allData.length) ? scrollDirection 
                                  : (scrollDirection < 0 && startPos + increment > increment) ? scrollDirection
                                  : 0;
                      updateTable();
                    });
```

Anyone know a better way to achieve this? Originally I just reversed the array and basing the startPos off the zoom scale, but this was causing problems with the zoom increment.

Anyway, to achieve the scrolling functionality you wanted I firstly loaded the data, generated the table head and body based off of the data, and then attached the scroll behaviour to the table body. I then sliced the data array to only contain the first 10 values (look at the 'startPos' and 'increment' variables) and populated the table based off of this sliced array. Everytime someone scrolls on the body of the table it updates the table with the 'updateTable' function.

Full code:

```
var keys, 
    allData, 
    currentData,
    startPos = 0,
    increment = 10;

var scrollEvent = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .on('zoom', function (e) { 
                      var scrollDirection = (d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY > 0) ? 1 : -1;
                      startPos += (scrollDirection > 0 && startPos + increment < allData.length) ? scrollDirection 
                                  : (scrollDirection < 0 && startPos + increment > 10) ? scrollDirection
                                  : 0;
                      updateTable();
                    });

var table = d3.select("#table").append("table")
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody").call(scrollEvent);

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/enjalot/1525346/raw/c4603a8d7dedc7e8c8f705ca8252a335b49e03dc/prices.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  keys     = Object.keys(data[0]),
  allData  = data;

  thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(keys).enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function (d) {
    return d;
  });

  updateTable();
});

function updateTable() {
  // Set new data based on startPos and increment.
  currentData = allData.slice(startPos, startPos + increment);

  // Delete previous rows.
  tbody.selectAll('tr').remove();

  // Create new rows.
  var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(currentData).enter()
                .append("tr")
                .classed("even", function(d, i) {
                  return i % 2 == 1; 
                });

      tr.selectAll('td')
        .data(function (d) { 
          return keys.map(function (e) {
            return { 
              key: e,
              value: d[e]
            }
          });
        }).enter()
        .append('td')
        .text(function (d) { 
          return d.value; 
        });
}
```

**Note:**

- This doesn't work for the scroll wheel event, you'll have to add that on/disable it if you want it/don't want it.
- CSV in the codepen is from this bl.ock: http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'll see, if I can enhance this solution to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise I missed any requirements, what did I leave out of my answer?

Comment: My main requirement is to have scrollable table body with fixed headers. Since, I have very limited knowledge of d3, I am not able to make out how to achieve vertical scrolling on top of your solution.

Comment: @NishantKansal My solution includes vertical scrolling, did you check this link? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrLVpv?editors=0010, hover your mouse over the table body and use your scroll wheel.

Comment: @NishantKansal If you include all of your code and your data I will be able to integrate my solution into your code and to fit your data, but without your actual data I'm forced to use the one in my solution.

Comment: With below code, I am able to set scroll on table body. However, if I change thead from "{
    position: relative;" to "{position: fixed;} in scroll.css to achieve FIXED headers, table body and headers are not aligned. If I keep it "relative", table headers and body are aligned but then headers are not static and on scroll headers goes with body. https://jsfiddle.net/nishant78/vdw2q1sm/6/

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: @NishantKansal I can't run your code because you haven't uploaded your componentlist.csv anywhere, if you upload your componentlist.csv file I can fix your code.

Comment: How I shall upload it? Here it is:

componentlist.csv

Status,Component,URL,Last
SUCCESS,ABC,google.co.in,Thu Jul 19 08:15:43 UTC 2018
SUCCESS,DEF,google.co.in,Thu Jul 19 08:16:22 UTC 2018
FAILURE,EFG,google.co.in,Thu Jul 19 08:18:49 UTC 2018
SUCCESS,HIJ,google.co.in,Thu Jul 19 08:18:09 UTC 2018